# Secure login & register system with hashed passwords

Tags: php, mysql, security, hash, passwords

So I have a table where I store user info like hashed passwords, emails, names etc. And I face this problem. When 2 users have the same password one of them can access other's account knowing their email. What solutions could you suggest? Thank you.

Here is how i try:

```
<?php
$pscoo = $_COOKIE['sw12Hj0i6y'];
$dthshcoo = $_COOKIE['dthsh'];

$pass = $_POST['pass']; // i get this from other page
$mail = $_POST['mail']; // i get this from other page

include 'admin/conn.php';

$get = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = '$mail'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $get);

if (!isset($pscoo) && !isset($dthsh)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $slt = $row['salt'];
    $hsh = $row['hash'];
    $cnct = $slt.$pass;
    if (password_verify($cnct, $hsh)) {
      // do smth
    }
    else {
      // reject
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: The odds of that happening is a bit slim, although possible. What you can do is to enforce a slightly more complex password check. Maybe force users to add an uppercase or special character?

Comment: Please share your code as this sounds like you have something wrong with it.

Comment: "When 2 users have the same password one of them can access other's account knowing their email"...true, but how likely is it that they would randomly try another person's account while using their own password? And what are the odds of them having identical passwords in the first place? If you enforce complex-enough password restrictions, then the odds of this should be tiny. Not sure this is a real problem, unless you have very relaxed password requirements, and/or very few users who can discover each others usernames easily.

Comment: @Rotimi I already have but I suspect that although this same passwords can occur. Thanks for response

Comment: @ADyson I force users to have complex passwords but I suspect that although this same passwords can occur. Thanks for response

Comment: @NigelRen I have already added. Thanks for response

Comment: So a user ONLY enters a password - otherwise you need to add a WHERE clause to your SELECT to only pick that users details up.

Comment: @NigelRen OK but even in that case when I enter other's mail that has also has the password as mine I will finally get in their page. So I imagine the case when DB leaks and attackers get all mails. Thanks

Comment: What's the exact problem you are facing? Two users with distinct mail addresses, but the same password, is not anything that sounds uncommon. But where's the problem with that?

Comment: This is theoretically a problem for any application in the world. But it's not a real problem. You talk about 2 users with the same password. But that is not significant. The fact that User A uses password X does not increase the probability that User B will also use password X. And the fact that User A knows password X does not increase the probability of them guessing User B's password. It is no more likely that X is User B's password than any other random combination of characters.

Comment: For your concern to be real, there would need to be some link between the two accounts, which somehow made it more likely those two users would share a password, and that one user might try to guess the other's password, and/or make the counter-intuitive assumption that they shared the same password. Without any evidence for that, then the situation is no different than any regular brute-force 
 password-hacking scenario.

Comment: You do have a much more serious security issue though, which needs fixing urgently - your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: Please fix the injection vulnerability in your code: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest to comply to following [OWASP Application Security Verification Standard](https://owasp.org/www-project-application-security-verification-standard/) (ASVS) password handling requirements:

> 2.1.1 Verify that user set passwords are at least 12 characters in length.
>
> 2.1.2 Verify that passwords 64 characters or longer are permitted
>
> 2.1.3 Verify that passwords can contain spaces and truncation is not performed
>
> 2.1.4 Verify that Unicode characters are permitted in passwords. A single Unicode code point is considered a character, so 12 emoji or 64
> kanji characters should be valid and permitted.
>
> 2.1.7 Verify that passwords submitted during account registration, login, and password change are checked against a set of breached
> passwords either locally (such as the top 1,000 or 10,000 most common
> passwords which match the system's password policy) or using an
> external API. If using an API a zero knowledge proof or other
> mechanism should be used to ensure that the plain text password is not
> sent or used in verifying the breach status of the password. If the
> password is breached, the application must require the user to set a
> new nonbreached password
>
> 2.1.8 Verify that a password strength meter is provided to help users set a stronger password.
>
> 2.1.9 Verify that there are no password composition rules limiting the type of characters permitted. There should be no requirement for upper
> or lower case or numbers or special characters.

NOTE: ASVS summarizes the best practice defined by security researchers, big security players (NIST) and common best practice. The requirements described in 2.1 chapter are Level 1 requirements meaning, that actually all newly built systems should fulfil them.

After doing of what is required above the possibility of collisions is minimal (negligible), but will always be there and should NOT be prevented. (Sometimes by preventing duplicate passwords people create a mechanism for user/password enumeration which is bad.)

Now, regarding your code. This place keeps me wondering:

```
$slt = $row['salt'];
$hsh = $row['hash'];
$cnct = $slt.$pass;
```

Usually a Key Derivation Function like bcrypt, scrypt, PBKDF2 should not need the salt to be concatenated to the password manually. Doing it like this would mean, you are not using a KDF, but some kind of hashing function (which is suboptimal from security perspective)... Suboptimal is wrong.

By the way, is this a SQL injection vulnerability: `$get = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE` mail `= '$mail'";` in your authentication logic? I so then **please have this fixed ASAP and update your question on StackOverflow too.**